# How to access an object instance loaded by the other classloader exception for using reflection?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm confused that how an object instance loaded by the other classloader can be accessed without the ClassCastExcepion being thrown except for using reflection?
It seems that using JndiObjectFactoryBean is a better idea,but I donot understand.
Is there anyone Can make me clear?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way (apart from reflection) is to always use an interface type to interact with the class; e.g.

```
public interface I {
    public void foo();
}

public class C implements I {
    public void foo(){ ... }
}

...
Classloader l1 = ...
I c1 = (I) l1.loadClass("some.pkg.C").newInstance();
c1.foo();

Classloader l2 = ...
I c2 = (I) l2.loadClass("some.pkg.C").newInstance();
c2.foo();
```

The interface `I` must loaded by a common ancestor classloader of `l1` and `l2`.  And assuming that these classloaders (`l1` and `l2`) actually loaded the classes, you cannot cast either `c1` or `c2` to `C`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I use JndiObjectFactoryBean to get a service instance which is bound by the other web application, and I directly cast the instance which is proxyed by JndiObjectFactoryBean to the type, it works well and no ClassCastException being thrown.
How do JndiObjectFactoryBean work?
Using the proxy can solve this?

Comment: I don't know whether a proxy would help in this case.  Why don't you try it?